# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\tan^{-1}x^2}{x^2(x^4-1)}-\frac{\pi}{4(x^4-1)}\>dx$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

How to Integrate

$$  I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\tan^{-1}x^2}{x^2(x^4-1)}-\frac{\pi}{4(x^4-1)} \>dx\approx -0.295512 $$

Mathematica returns a result that does not match numerically with the integral approximation :

$$ \frac{i C}{4} -\frac{\pi}{4}\sqrt{4-3i} +\frac{3 \pi^2}{32} +\pi\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{i}{8}\right)\coth^{-1}(\sqrt{2}) \approx -0.048576 + 0.43823\,i $$

[image]

Where C denotes Catalan's Constant

**Motivation**

I was able to find a closed form for

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\tan^{-1}(x^2)}{x^2(x^4-1)}-\frac{\pi}{4(x^4-1)}dx $$

using double infinite sums. Upon plotting the function within the integral i saw that it could be integrated from $0$ to ${\infty}$ .

**Attempts**

*Number 1*

I tried to Split the integral as

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\tan^{-1}(x^2)}{x^2(x^4-1)}-\frac{\pi}{4(x^4-1)}dx + \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\tan^{-1}(x^2)}{x^2(x^4-1)}-\frac{\pi}{4(x^4-1)}dx $$

and use the Taylor Series for $\tan^{-1}(x^2) $ when $|x| >1$

*Number 2*

I tried using partial fractions as

$$ \frac{1}{x^4-1} = \frac{1}{4(x-1)} - \frac{1}{4(x+1)} -\frac{1}{2(x^2+1)} $$

$$ \frac{1}{x^2(x^4-1)} = \frac{1}{2(x^2+1)}-\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{4(x+1)} + \frac{1}{4(x-1)} $$

from which I obtained

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\tan^{-1}(x^2)}{2(x^2+1)}dx = \frac{\pi^2}{16} $$
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\pi}{8(x^2+1)} dx= \frac{\pi^2}{8} $$

but was unable to proceed further.

*Number 3*

A number of basic integration techniques such as U-Sub and Integration by parts.

*Number 4*

Using the same technique i used to evaluate the same integral but from $0$ to $1$

I will continue to try , but for now I find myself to be stuck.

Q - Is there a closed form for I? If the solution is easy and i am missing something , could you provide hints instead?

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: How did you show that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\tan^{-1}(x^2)}{2(x^2+1)}dx = \frac{\pi^2}{16}$$?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent my best friend Mathematica, although i could probably do it by hand, with enough time.

Comment: I'm no longer stumped, I've now proved it! A very nice integral indeed. :)

Comment: @A-LevelStudent very nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note
$$\frac1{x^4-1} =\frac1{2(x^2-1)} - \frac1{2(x^2+1)}\\
\frac1{x^2(x^4-1)} =\frac1{2(x^2-1)} + \frac1{2(x^2+1)}-\frac1{x^2}
$$
and rewrite the integral as

\begin{align}
 I &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{\tan^{-1}x^2}{x^2(x^4-1)}-\frac{\pi}{4(x^4-1)} \right)dx\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{16}+ \frac12\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\tan^{-1}x^2}{1+x^2}dx
 - \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\tan^{-1}x^2}{x^2}dx
 + \frac12\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\tan^{-1}x^2-\frac\pi4}{x^2-1}dx\tag1
\end{align}
where $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\tan^{-1}x^2}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{\pi^2}8$, $
 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\tan^{-1}x^2}{x^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt2}$ and

\begin{align}
&\frac12\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\tan^{-1}x^2-\frac\pi4}{x^2-1}dx
=\int_0^{1} \frac{\tan^{-1}x^2-\frac\pi4}{x^2-1}dx\\
\overset{IBP}=&-\int_0^1 \frac x{1+x^4} \ln \frac{1-x}{1+x}dx
\overset{x\to \frac{1-x}{1+x}}=-\int_0^\infty\frac {\ln x}{1+6x^2+ x^4}dx\\
 =&-\frac1{4\sqrt2}\left( \int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{x^2+ (\sqrt2-1)^2}dx -\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{x^2+ (\sqrt2+1)^2}dx \right)\\
 =&-\frac1{8\sqrt2}\left(\frac{\ln(\sqrt2-1)}{\sqrt2-1} - \frac{\ln(\sqrt2+1)}{\sqrt2+1} \right)
\end{align}
Substitute above results into (1) to obtain

$$I= \frac{\pi^2}8-\frac\pi{\sqrt2}\left(1+\frac{\ln(\sqrt2-1)}{8(\sqrt2-1)} - \frac{\ln(\sqrt2+1)}{8(\sqrt2+1)} \right)
$$

Comment: should've worked harder before posting the problem, thanks for the nice solution @Quanto

Comment: Your integration skills are awesome; virtually every tough integral that comes up these days has an answer written by you eventually. Thank you for your hard work, I really appreciate your contributions, and I learn a lot from them too!

Comment: @A-LevelStudent - appreciate the compliment

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this myself, but this problem reminds me of something I saw in complex analysis with the [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem). For the second part (after the minus sign) a good contour would just be the upper half of a semicircle, in combination with a line along the Real axis (see picture). Again, I have not yet tested if the correct integrals cancel out, but this is my current guess for an additional approach.

[image: contour in the complex plane, where [-a, a] might be the Re-axis and j may be an isolated singularity]

For the first part of the integral, a contour like below may be more appropriate, since 0 is also a singularity.

[image: indented contour since 0 is a singularity]

The reason we like these particular contours is that we should somehow show the complex part of the path is 0 (or apply [Jordan's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma), if we can), and so we can limit the Real axis piece to get $[-\infty, \infty]$ and get the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value). Further, your functions are even functions, so we can then at the end split in half to get the upper half of the integral.

This is a guess! I will attempt and edit if there are troubles, or if I think of another way!

### EDIT:

Because of singularities along the real axis, you will have to do something closer to the second contour, with the indent, around $z = \pm 1$. But writing it all down, I believe this integral is not too difficult (i.e., can be done by hand) using this method of contour integration, and then evenness at the end.

Comment: Thank you , i don't have much experience with contour integration , but i will look around to see if i can make sense of it.